# install .app file on MacOS via script?

Tags: mac-osx, installation, application

I have an .app executable generated for MacOSX. Is it any easy way to install this app into Applications so it can be used by end users, via script? (need to install on multiple computers and really don't want to create intermediate .pkg installer for it)

Comment: How are you planning on deploying it? ssh to a box and run a script? Using something like Apple Remote Desktop or the Casper Suite?  Or did you want a script that end users can run that will download and install the .app?

Comment: You don't need to "install" it. It's just a matter of copying .app directory there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a specific example:

```
scp -r /Applications/Opera.app sysadmin@CES-iBookGr4-88.local:/Applications
```

This recursively copies the folder for, in this example, the Opera web browser, from my computer to a computer (named CES-iBookGR4-88) that I have an ssh account on.

More generically:

```
scp -r /Applications/{App.app} {user}@{RemoteDestination}:/Applications
```

Where App.app represents the application and the remote destination is the IP name or address of a computer that you have a user account on with ssh access.  (Turn on Remote Login in the Sharing Preferences).

To go the other way, do this:

```
scp -r {user}@{RemoteSource}:/Applications/{App.app} /Applications
```

In both cases, you will likely be asked to verify the other computer (just type in yes when asked to id it) and will be asked for the user's password.

Comment: and if some clients may already have this app, then rsync would work well.